# CSS p element created in a new section ineherinting properties from a different section which has its own class name

Tags: html, css

I hava a p element which somehow is inheriting CSS properties from a different section which has its own class name.
This is a [image: a screenshot of my code]

```
HTML 
     <section>
        <div class="features-container">
            <div class="card-one">
                <i class="fas fa-hotel fa-3x"></i>
                <h1 class="card-title">Great Location</h1>
                <p class="card-para" > Lorem ipsum    dolor sit amet consectetur</p>
            </div>
```

CodeSnippet:
https://codepen.io/Helye23/pen/LYGJELr

Any idea?
Thanks!!

Comment: Please share your code/snippet

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre]. All code relevant to your problem belongs directly into your question, in text form & properly formatted. Do not show “images of” code, and do not just dump it onto an external platform.

Comment: @Sfili_81 the code snippet should now be in the post. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Your comma in your info-content class means your targeting your p tag outside the class.
Try this istead:

```
.info-content h2, .info-content p {
    padding: 10px 100px 20px;
    color: white;
}
```

You may want to adjust this due to padding but this example means you are no longer target all p classes.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_comma.asp

Comment: thank you! You taught me something today. I thought the way I was doing was the correct one and that you didn't need to repeat the class name if your element was immediately following the previous one. Thanks again!

Comment: if you do not want to repeat CSS class look into child combinators
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_gt.asp